# Rails 4.1 - thinking-sphinx association not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have a Rails app that contains two models, `Post` and `User`, I'm using `Sphinx` and the `thinking-sphinx` gem to enable search. Each post belongs to a user, with `belongs_to`, and each user can have many posts. When I search for posts I also want to be able to search by the user's name that have created the post. My index for Posts looks like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :post, :with => :active_record do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes post_description
  indexes user.name, as: :post_user

  has user_id, team_id, created_at, updated_at
end
```

My user index looks like this:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :user, :with => :active_record do
  indexes name, :sortable => true
  indexes email
  indexes about

  has team_id, created_at, updated_at
end
```

When I run: `rake ts:index`, I get the following error:

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `_reflect_on_association' for #<Class:0x007fd417610c90>
```

Any ideas on how I can solove it?

**Update**

I'm pretty sure that it's this line that causes he `indexes user.name, as: :post_user`, when I don't get any errors. But the association still doesn't work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to an update in the `joiner` gem (version `0.3.2`), which requires `Rails >= 4.1.2`.

See this commit: https://github.com/pat/joiner/commit/de1403ec85d21dabf21a715ae962ee31c6ffe8d1

Either update to Rails 4.1.2 or add the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'joiner', '0.3.1'
```